# como puedo hacer que una barra de busqueda sea funcional?

Tags: css, html5, buscador

ya tengo la barra de busqueda creado con hover, pero no se como hacer que sea funcional, que me lleve a lo que yo escribo, no se si se me entiende, quiero que esta barra de busqueda sea funcional pero no se como hacerlo, por ejemplo: la barra de busqueda de google, y nada mas, esto me pide que ponga mas detalles porque no me deja guardar los cambios

```css
*{
 margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
box-sizing: border-box;

}
body{
font-family: sans-serif;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
height: 100vh;
background: linear-gradient( #2c0be6, #001efc);
}
.buscar{
position: absolute;
padding: 5px;

}
.buscar input{
width: 0px;
height: 40px;
padding: 0 20px;
font-size: 18px;
color: black;
outline: none;
border: 1px solid silver;
border-radius: 30px;
transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
.btn{
width: 55px;
height: 55px;
line-height: 55px;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
background-color: #440080;
line-height: 55px;
text-align: center;
color: whitesmoke;
font-size: 20px;
border-radius: 50%;
cursor: pointer;
}
.buscar:hover input{
width: 240px;


}
.buscar input:focus{

    width: 240px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2e83633af7.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>buscador</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="buscar">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar" required>
        <div class="btn">
            <i class="fas fa-search-dollar"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: Es muy poca información como para que te podamos ayudar. Qué probaste? Publicá el código que tenés. Danos más detalles, etc. Te recomiendo que leas [ask].

Comment: solamente tengo el codigo de la barra de busqueda creado, pero no se como hacer que sea funcional, por ejemplo: la barra de busqueda de google, cuando buscas algo te lleva a lo que buscaste, bueno algo asi. igual mi codigo de la bara es este

Comment: edito la pregunta para que se pueda ver el codigo

Comment: a que te refieres con "funcional"? si te refieres a que cuando escribas algo, "busque" por internet, entonces tienes que hacer mas cosas. Ahi con el html y el css solo dibujas una pagina. Tienes que hacer una aplicacion, a la que le mandas ese algo y se encargue de buscar (en bbdd, en internet, donde tu lo definas) y te devuelva esos datos...

Comment: claro, a eso viene mi pregunta, quisiera saber como se podria hacer eso

Comment: (...) "me pide que ponga mas detalles porque no me deja guardar los cambios": es porque debes agregar un [repro], énfasis en _mínimo_. Me animaría a decir que tu pregunta es bastante amplia, porque hay muchas formas de hacer lo que preguntás. No basta con HTML y CSS. Tendrías que delimitar bien qué exactamente buscás (dando más detalles) y mostrar qué intentaste para que la búsqueda en el campo en verdad sea funcional. Como te han indicado, lee [ask].

Comment: Si lo que pretendes es hacer un Google no se si lo conseguiras así.  Si lo que pretendes es usar a Google para que te haga las busquedas y te las muestre en tu buscador eso ya es más facil, aunque tampoco tanto si se usa intensamente porque google no lo permite asi como asi. Para ello deberias usar algun codigo de programación como PHP o python conjuntamente con alguna libreria como CURL, aparte de javascript para hacer la busqueda conforme vas escribiendo, y nada mas.

Comment: Resumiendo lo que te han dicho: HTML y CSS solo sirven para *dibujar* interfaces. Si quieres que tu dibujo haga algo, necesitas *programar* algo de lógica. Para eso debes usar javascript. Y si necesitas hacer algo *"complejo"* seguramente te interese tener un backend (un servidor para atender el "trabajo" de tu web) escrito en el lenguaje que más te apetezca, puesto que aquí ya casi no tienes limitaciones (excepto tus conocimientos). Las web estáticas (html + css) no pueden hacer nada por si solas, son solo eso, estáticas.

Comment: si,si lo se pero quisiera saber como hacerlo en java o en cualquier lenguaje, por eso mi pregunta jaja